# Can I place most of my PHP code inside a PhoneGap app and port to iphone and androids?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I can't seem to find any good resources to help me with this. Hopefully some experts can chime in. thanks.

I'm basically just trying to port our web app, and make it an app for iphone and android. i'd like to do the minimum amount necessary in order to get it to work.

Mostly basic features:

1) login / signup, etc.
2) get data and info from our remote database
3) perform actions, like buy credits for our system, and sync it with their account
4) send text within the applicalition to another user, also in our application.
5) transmit video from 1 phone, to the other user, on phone or computer
6) maybe be able to set reminders for events and place it in their phones calendar. not sure though.

we plan on using bootstrap and javascript (or jquery mobile) for any special functionalities

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run PHP code in an phonegap application. need to convert all your server response to web services. Then you can get data from ajax call

A simple example may be

PHP - In SERVER

```
<?php 
    extract($_REQUEST); // submitting username password 
    if($username=='admin' && $password=='1234' ) 
        echo '{"login":"success"}'; // sending response as login success 
    else 
        echo '{"login":"fail"}'; // sending response as login fail 
?>
```

In phonegap rise a ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://domain.com/above-code.php",
    data: {
        "username": $('input.username').val(),
        "password": $('input.password').val()
    }
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.login == "success") {
            alert(" login successful ");
            window.location = "dashboard. HTML";
        } else {
            alert(" login fail ");
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```